# Autocomplete LaTeX math mode in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I do my LaTeX work in VS code. I use the LaTeX Workshop extension. Is there anyway to auto complete `\(\)` and `\[\]` in VS code? I would like it to behave similar to `{}` or `()`. That is, when I open a bracket `(` it automatically closes the bracket and places the cursor in the middle. Currently, when I open an inline math mode with `\(`, it shows me a drop down (as shown in the screenshot) and completes it only if I press <kbd>return</kbd>.

[image]

Is there any extension (that doesn't clash with LateX workshop) that does this? If not, is there any snippet that I could use? Thanks.